# Force a Class Method Parameter to be a Constant From an Abstract Class

Tags: php, class, oop, enums

**Integration Trait**

```
trait Integration {
    public function executeRequest($url, $method, $data, $acceptType) {
        //Do Something
    }
}
```

**Rest Accept Type Abstract Class**

```
abstract class RestAcceptType {
    const xml= "text/xml";
    const html = "text/html";
    const json = "application/json";
    const text = "text/plain";
}
```

I am trying to find a way to require the `$acceptType` method parameter to be a constant from the Rest Accept Type abstract class.

ie:

```
$a = new Integration;
$a->executeRequest("http://example.com/endpoint", "POST", $dataArray, RestAcceptType::json);
```

works but...

```
$a = new Integration;
$a->executeRequest("http://example.com/endpoint", "POST", $dataArray, "json");
```

should fail and throw a fatal exception. Would like to ideally do this through type hinting but can do it as a separate data type validation stage within the method itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this with type-hinting, unfortunately. [Type hints can only operate at the level of class, interface or scalar-type level](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration).

Commonly, this pattern is achieved by giving your class a list of "known" constants, which you can then check either via a method on the same class, or a simple `in_array` check if you make the list public. So you might add the following to the `RestAcceptType` class:

```
public static function isValidAcceptType($type)
{
    return in_array($type, [
        self::xml,
        self::html,
        self::json,
        self::text,
    ]);
}
```

You could then use this at the top of your `executeRequest` method using something like:

```
if (!RestAcceptType::isValidAcceptType($acceptType)) {
  throw new InvalidArgumentException;
}
```

I appreciate this isn't the cleanest pattern (particularly since it means making two changes when you add a new constant), but short of using something like [`ReflectionClass::getConstants`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getconstants.php), it isn't possible to iterate over a class's constants. In my opinion at least, that wouldn't be particularly clean either (although that's exactly how the library in the other answer works, so it is definitely an option).

Comment: I wound up going this way for the time being only as it does not require the integration of an additional library into the code base in order to work. Having said that I do look forward to when PHP releases the SPL extension to general availability and takes it out of experimentation so that it is production ready.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a library like [php-enum](https://github.com/marc-mabe/php-enum). Then you can type hint enum type:

```
final class RestAcceptType extends Enum {
    public const XML = "text/xml";
    public const HTML = "text/html";
    public const JSON = "application/json";
    public const TEXT = "text/plain";
}

trait Integration {
    public function executeRequest($url, $method, $data, RestAcceptType $acceptType) {
        //Do Something
    }
}

$a = new class {
    use Integration;
};

$a->executeRequest("http://example.com/endpoint", "POST", $dataArray, RestAcceptType::JSON());
```

Pay attention that you are not accessing a constant here, but instead calling a static method that returns singleton.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use [SplEnum](http://php.net/manual/es/class.splenum.php), which is as close to "standard" as you are going to get.

```
class RestAcceptType extends SplEnum {

    const __default = self::xml;

    const xml= "text/xml";
    const html = "text/html";
    const json = "application/json";
    const text = "text/plain";
}

trait Integration {
  public function executeRequest($url, $method, $data, RestAcceptType $acceptType) {
    //Do Something
  }
}

$acceptType = new RestAcceptType(RestAcceptType::xml);
```

Comment: This is one of the options I was looking at but unfortunately PHP still has this PECL extension listed as experimental which for the purposes of this project i'm not too keen on. Otherwise I agree this would absolutely be the best option under the circumstances and as soon as PHP takes this extension out of experimentation and marks it as production ready I think it will be the best way to go for enumerated value restrictions.